# Power distribution between the City Council and County Council in US city/counties

Tags: united-states, local-government

For example, I am looking at the Salt Lake County and Salt Lake City. SLCity is a large part of the county and both levels of government have an elected council. Furthermore the county has another plethora of elected officials (and the city too) such as a District Attorney and a county Mayor. Does the county government have any direct influence on the municipality of Salt Lake City? Who can vote for whom?

Who does what here? Isn't this a bit too much of local government? This system to me seems cluttered.

Comment: FYI, In many cases, the city is officially NOT part of the county it resides in

Comment: @user4012 I find that hard to believe. Can you source it? I know some states give "Class A Municipalities" (big cities) immunity from county regulations, but that doesn't mean they're not part of the county.

Comment: @barrycarter - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_city_(United_States)

Comment: Well, ok, 38 in VA and 3 elsewhere. I don't think that qualifies as "in many cases".

Comment: This really depends on which counties/cities you are talking about as it varies in each case, generally based upon the state/city's founding doctrines.

Comment: Yes, no, and maybe.  There's so much variation across the United States that you really need to narrow it down to a specific state (and in some cases, a specific county).